# Confusion about static and non-static access to variables

Tags: java

Why field `A` can be non-static. But when I remove `static` from fields `B`, `C` or `D` I get a compile error.

This is a guess from one resource and I want to understand why I can do field `A` without `static`.

```
public class Solution
{
    public int A = 5;
    public static int B = 5;
    public static int C = 5;
    public static int D = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Solution solution = new Solution();
        solution.A = 5;
        solution.B = 5 * B;
        solution.C = 5 * C * D;
        Solution.D = 5 * D * C;
        Solution.D = 5;
    }

    public int getA()
    {
        return A;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should know that `solution.B = 5 * B;` contains _two_ different ways of accessing `B`. `solution.B` is not the same as `B`, that is way `B` currently needs be `static`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, a class can have two types of class members:

1. **Instance members**: Instance member belongs to the instance (object) of the class. e.g. variable `A` in your code. Instance variables have separate copy (memory allocated) for each object of the class. Instance member can be directly accessed in `non-static` context and require instance (object) to be accessed in `static` context.
2. **Static Members**: `static` members belongs to the class. Only one copy of each variable exist for a class. `static` members can be accessed directly in the class anywhere. e.g. variable `B`, `C` and `D` in your code.

---

```
Solution solution = new Solution();
solution.A = 5;    // 
solution.B = 5 * B;
solution.C = 5 * C * D;
Solution.D = 5 * D * C;

Solution.D = 5;
```

See this code block, because `A` is instance member of the class, so you are accessing it using the instance of the class `solution`. Where as all the other are `static` member of the class. The `static` members belong to the class and can be accessed directly in the `static` context. `main()` is a `static` method.

When you remove the `static` from other variable `(B, C, D)`, you need to access them using a instance of the class, because they becomes the instance member of the class and need a object reference to access them.

Also note that `static` members can be accessed using the instance of the class. For example using doing it `solution.C`, here `C` is `static` member, but can be accessed using the instance of the class. same applied to the `B` and `D`.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to put it simple. Static means, that this method or variable can be used, without having an object of that class

without static:

```
Solution solution = new Solution();
solution.A = 5;
```

with static:

```
        **S**olution.B = 5 * B;
        **S**olution.C = 5 * C * D;
        Solution.D = 5 * D * C;
```

note that if u call it with the Solution (big S), ure referring to the class, while solution (small s) is the object of the class

since ure using B, C, D without the "solution" infront of it it assumes u mean to call it static (just like Solution.B)

your code "corrected":

```
public class Solution
{
    public int A = 5;
    public int B = 5;
    public int C = 5;
    public int D = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Solution solution = new Solution();
        solution.A = 5;
        solution.B = 5 * solution.B;
        solution.C = 5 * solution.C * solution.D;
        solution.D = 5 * solution.D * solution.C;

        Solution.D = 5;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With code:

```
Solution solution = new Solution();
```

You're creating an object of your class Solution. Therefore you have an instance and

```
solution.A
```

is not static access (and neither are the other field accesses for that matter). This code should generate a warning which tells you this (at least Eclipse & IDEA do).